# html5 videos not showing controls on android once loaded

Tags: cordova, html5-video, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

Good day. I am currently working on a hybrid app using framework7 which has an html5 video. The video works fine and loads just ok but whenever the video goes on fullscreen or the controls disappear from the video player interface it wont show up again when I press the video playing. I am using `<video width="100%" height="auto" controls </video>`. Would there be a way to fix this or is this a limitation on the hybrid app itself? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should close your html tags `<video width="100%" height="auto" controls> </video>`

Comment: sorry that was just a typo with the closing on the video tag. I wrote it the same way that you did but still the same problem

Answer (score 3):

That issue is caused by fastclick. Add class no-fastclick to your video tag and it will solve your issue.

Comment: If I could upvote you a hundred thousand times I would. This killed me for going on 2 weeks now. I thought it was a Cordova/PhoneGap issue for the longest time. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This totally solved the problem of playing video. The video could seek to different times, but it wouldn't play. Ref: https://framework7.io/docs/fast-clicks.html