# Cordova, HTML5 Video not responding to touch inputs

Tags: html, cordova, html-framework-7

***Update:***
I did a fully build via Android studios, and the HTML5 Video does not work at all. It may be related to it targeting a web site? Though I can have the app open a website from the app directly, so maybe something else I am missing. I also tried with the video in the app directory, but again, it did not seem to load at all.

---

I am building a `Cordova/Framework7` app that I need to embed videos into.
The video loads, and I can scroll back and forth through the video, but the giant PLAY button does not respond when touching it in app.

```
<video id='video' controls>
    <source src="https://website.com/FancyVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video
</video>
```

I've tried to make an event listener to trigger the video (with and without the onload bi)

```
window.onload = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.addEventListener('click', function () {
        video.play();
    }, false);
}
```

So I am not sure what to do, it should work. 
I have followed several other question threads but none seem to work, or are mostly obsolete. I have also tried media plugins with similar results.

[HTML5  element on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android)

[html5 videos not showing controls on android once loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558500/html5-videos-not-showing-controls-on-android-once-loaded)

*Note:*
I am using

```
PhoneGap desktop application, and a Galaxy S7 running Android 8.0.0
Cordova Android Version 7.1.0
Cordova Version 8.0.0
Framework 7 Version 3.0.1
PhoneGap Version 8.0.0
```

[image: Image of the app with video]